# Is there a way to ownerdraw (or something similar) a MainMenu in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, menubar, aero, dwm

I'm trying to create a MainMenu for my application that looks similar to the one used by Mozilla Firefox:

[image]

So that it displays over aero glass. I can think of a few ways to do this, except they would be ugly, and probably ruin the experience of the program due to them being hackish.

I'm wondering if there is a way to custom draw the `MainMenu` control, similar to how you can override the `OnPaint` method on other controls (which for some reason, `MainMenu` doesn't have). Or if that is not possible, what sort of hacky ways could I use that wouldn't ruin the UX.

Yes, I'm sure there is a ridiculously easy way to do this in WPF, and I would love to be able to take the time to learn it, but my application is already in a semi-mature stage, and it would be extremely inconvenient to switch to a different UI platform at this point.

Comment: http://windowsformsaero.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for replying. The first link redirects to my own list of articles (of which I have none), and I am aware of the project at the second link, but I don't see how it helps me with my question. Perhaps I should read its documentation again?

Comment: Wow, that was weird... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15394/Drawing-smooth-text-and-pictures-on-the-extended-g

Comment: Even so, as far as I can tell, neither of those projects mentions anything about menus.

Comment: IMHO Firefox's attempts at incorporating glass into their UI are more attempts than actual well-done solutions. You might rather want to take a look at Paint.NET in that regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating my own control that inherits ToolStripMenuItem and overriding OnPaint and drawing the text with `DrawThemeTextEx`, and using a modified version of the MenuStrip renderer found [here](http://code.google.com/p/szotar/source/browse/trunk/Client/Szotar.WindowsForms/Base/NativeToolStripRenderer.cs) that omits the rendering of header text (so it doesn't conflict with `DrawThemeTextEx` and the background bar of the ToolStrip.

Final product looks like this:

[image: :)]

Comment: Very nice! Mind sharing with a Gist or something similar?